# Possible to encrypt external drive for use on Linux and MacOS?

Tags: usb, encryption, mac

I have two computers, a Linux and a Mac. I'd like an external drive I could use on both OSs that would be password protected. Is this possible?

Comment: "Password-protected" is not the same as "encrypted". Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

A better solution more modern is https://www.cryfs.org/

The current version has some security issue .
https://defuse.ca/audits/encfs.htm

=======================================

A solution that is working between MacOs and Linux is to use `encfs`

On you Mac :

1. Format a USB key with :

   - scheme: Master Boot Record
   - format: ExFat
   - Name: TestEncFs. **<= choose what you want**
2. with a terminal :

   - `ls /Volumes/TestEncFs/`
   - create or copy a file
   - umount with `diskutil umount /Volumes/TestEncFs`
   - unplug you usb key

On your linux box :

3. plug your usb key
4. with a terminal

- install `encfs` with `sudo apt-get install encfs`
- initialize the encryption layer with :
  `encfs /media/USERNAME/TestEncFs/  ~/TestEncFs`
- go inside the new folder in `~/TestEncFs/`
- copy or create a file into

if you run :

- `ls -la /media/USERNAME/TestEncFs/`  all files that was created on folder `~/TestEncFs/`  are encrypted , the other are clear
- `ls -la ~/TestEncFs/` you will see the clear version
- to umount :
  `encfs -u TestEncFs/` stop the ciphering layer

  `umount /media/USERNAME/TestEncFs/` umount your usb key

On your mac you must install
`encfs` via `brew install encfs`

`brew` can be found at https://brew.sh

Answer (score 0):

A simple turn-key solution for encryption that works on Linux, Mac and Windows is [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html). You can use it to encrypt an entire partition or only file containers on a partition/drive.